# Return unique row using a query formula

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have a data as shown in the spreadsheet ([Here is the link to sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IsNoReCmUq9hzF0NsNMuoJdA2Y6EZwihUPVVuHxhVdM/copy))

Where I need to get the uniques when both columns B and C considered, The col B is a date type

```
=QUERY(UNIQUE(FILTER(A:E,C:C="Daniel Workman")))
```

The expected result is indicated in yellow color

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=FILTER(A9:E18, COUNTIFS(B9:B18&C9:C18, B9:B18&C9:C18)=1, C9:C18="Daniel Wokman")
```

and:

```
=FILTER(A9:E18, COUNTIFS(B9:B18&C9:C18, B9:B18&C9:C18)=1, C9:C18="Morgan Freeman")
```

[image]